# get pointer value from parameter

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning how to use pointers in C and I am having trouble with this little program. In main, I want to get the value in the parameter.

```
int testing(int *number)  {

   int num = 12;
   number = &num;
   return 0;
}


int main() {

   int num;
   testing(&num);
   printf("The number is: %d", num);

   return 0;
}
```

Essentially, I want to print the num pointer after it goes through the testing function. Therefore, I want num to be 12. Currently, when I print num, it is a random number. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`number = &num;` is changing the local parameter (copy of what is passed). This means nothing because `number` is not used after that.

Instead of that, you should dereference the passed pointer to write the integer there: `*number = num;`

Answer (score 1):

This is a fundamental issue in your code. If pass a function argument by reference you actually pass a copy of the address of your value to the function. Therefore changing the address inside a function like you do with the lines:

```
int num = 12;
number = &num;
```

does not have an impact in the caller scope (your main).
You have to write the value at the position of the variable:

```
*number = num
```

In C it helps to think in addresses and where your values are stored. From an hardware point of view a function argument is placed in a register or on the stack and the CPU jumps to the location of your function. These values are not retrieved after the function terminates and the CPU jumps back.

Comment: In C it helps to think like that, but not in C++ unless you're maintaining a very old code base. And a bit nitpicking: C doesn't really have "pass by reference". It's all pass by value. C++ has both references and pointers.

Comment: I would not say that. When you use C++ without STL or you are using an older C++ std for whatever reason you have to work with pointers. Moreover in C terminology call-by-reference refers to a pointer. Only in C++ there is a distinction in the terminology and a C++ reference is also resolved with a pointer/address by the compiler. But I get your point :D

Comment: @AlexanderFratzer True, but how common is c++ without stl for developing new stuff?

Comment: @klutt In embedded systems e.g. or if you have real-time, memory constraints or a style-guide in a safty-critical context. But I admit that C++ is often not the first choice under these conditions but I use it when I have the choice because I like OO when it makes sense ;). It depends on the abstraction level you are working with.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the advice, its done

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that, you should dereference the passed pointer to write the integer there:

```
*number = num;
```